# Save a file style.min.css automatically when I save my style.css or .js on sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2

I would like to know if a plugin for SublimeText is available to optimise automatically my .css and .js (like http://cleancss.com/) when i save my file  ?

Like that, in my html code I have just to link my .min.css instead of .css and it's always updated.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Package Control and search for [`minify`](https://sublime.wbond.net/search/minify) you'll get a number of options. It looks like some of them are web-based, and some rely on local compilers. There are also a couple that only do JavaScript, and the rest do JS and CSS.

Good luck!